# Repartition and Shuffles in Spark Physical Plans

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to understand Spark (2.4) Physical Plans. We interact with Spark via the SQL API.

I am using the following sql. The sql has one aggregation in Step 1 and a join operation in the next step. My intention was to `repartition` the source table before the step 1 so that I could re-use this `Exchange` and avoid `Shuffles` (`Exchanges`) in the following steps, but it did not work as per my expectation. Could you please help me understand where I am going wrong.

```
    create or replace temporary view prsn_dtl as
    select
    policy_num,
    prsn_id,
    eff_dt,
    from db.person_details
    cluster by policy_num;
    
    create or replace temporary view plcy_dtl as
    select
    policy_num,
    role_desc,
    prsn_actv_flg
    from plcy_detail
    
    create or replace temporary view my_keys as
    select
    policy_num as policy_num,
    prsn_id as prsn_id,
    max(eff_dt) as eff_dt
    from prsn_dtl
    group by 1, 2;
    
    select
    keys.policy_num,
    keys.prsn_id,
    keys.eff_dt,
    plcy.role_desc,
    plcy.prsn_actv_flg
    from my_keys keys
    inner join plcy_dtl plcy
    on keys.policy_num = plcy.policy_num;
```

In the DAG representation I found 3 `Exchanges` -
Step 1) First one `hashpartitioning(policy_num#92, 200)` due to `cluster by` before the `aggregate`
Step 2) Second was between the `Aggregate` operators on `hashpartitioning(policy_num#163, prsn_id#164, 200)`
Step 3) Finally `hashpartitioning(policy_num#163)` before the sort-merge Join

My question :
why did not the `Exchange` (from `cluster by`) from Step 1 above, get propagated down and was not re-used in Step 3 before the Sort-Merge Join.

My expectation was that Spark will reuse the `Exchange` from Step 1 (`cluster by`) and will not add another `Exchange` (before the SMJ) in Step 3, since both were `repartitioned` on policy_num.

Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong.

**UPDATE**:
Physical Plan:-

```
CollectLimit 1
        +- *(6) Project [policy_num#836, prsn_id#837, eff_dt#838, role_desc#304, prsn_actv_flg#306]
          +- *(6) SortMergeJoin [policy_num#836], [policy_num#300], Inner 
    :       +- *(3) Sort [policy_num#836 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
    :        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(policy_num#836, 200)
    :         +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=policy_num#801, prsn_id#802], functions=[max(eff_dt)], output=[policy_num#836, prsn_id#837, eff_dt#838])
    :           +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[policy_num#801, prsn_id#802], functions=[partial_max(eff_dt#803)], output=[policy#801, prsn_id#802, max#847]) 
    :             +- *(2) Sort [policy_num#801 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0 
    :               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(policy_num#801, 200)
    :                +- *(1) Project [policy_num#801, prsn_id#802, eff_dt#803]
    :                  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(policy_num#801)     
    :                   +-   *(1) Filescan parquet testdb.prsn_details[policy_num#801,prsn_id#802,eff_dt#803] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://test_db.prsn_details/20200505..., PartitionFilters: [], PushFilters: [IsNotNull(policy_num)], ReadSchema: struct<policy_num:string, prsn_id:string, eff_dt:date>              
               +- *(5) Sort [policy_num#300 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0  
                +- Exchange hashpartitioning(policy_num#300, 200)
                  +- *(4) Project [policy_num#300, role_desc#304, prsn_actv_flg#306]
                   +- *(4) Filter (((trim(prsn_actv_flg#306, None) = ) ................
                     +- *(4) Filescan parquet
plcy_detail[policy_num#300,role_desc#304,prsn_actv_flg#306] Batched: true, Format: Parquet,
Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://test_db.plcy_details/20200505..., PartitionFilters: [], PushFilters: [IsNotNull(policy_num)], ReadSchema: struct<policy_num:string, role_desc:string, prsn_actv_flg:string>
```

**UPDATE II**: (SOLUTION):- Removed the column renaming (`AS`) from the `GROUP BY` query and now the exchange is being re-used in the query plan:

```
create or replace temporary view my_keys as
select
policy_num,
prsn_id,
max(eff_dt) as eff_dt
from prsn_dtl
group by 1, 2;
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide here the entire physical plan?

Comment: @David I have updated the question with the physical plan.. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Thanks for providing the plan. I actually wasn't able to reproduce it with my tables of similar structure. In my plan, the last `Exchange` is not there. What is the specific spark version that you used? I tried with 2.4.4 and 2.4.5. Is the query in the question just a simplified version or is it the entire query that produced the plan? From the plan you can see what is the problem - the last `HashAggregate` has different attributes in keys and in the output, they are renamed policy_num#801 -> policy_num#836 and the last `Exchange` is using this renamed field. This doesn't happen in my plan.

Comment: @DavidVrba i found the reason for the issue - i was renaming the columns in the query with the `Group By` clause, hence Spark was treating this column as a different column and hence not re-using the exchange. Now I have removed the `AS column-name`  part and hence Spark is re-using the the exchange and creating the plan as expected.

Comment: Also, could you please let me know what the numbers within parentheses signify in the query physical plan ? For e.g. `+- *(5)` and `+- *(2)` etc..

Comment: The numbers in the parentheses signify the order of the execution of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your specified query the exact one you have mentioned here ? Or is it part of a bigger query ? Spark will re-use the `exchange` if the `aggregate` keys are a subset of the re-partitioned key. The issue could be because the columns are being renamed between your queries. If your query has aliases you might want to remove them and then check again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're grouping by policy_num and prsn_id you incur a new shuffle, then again in order to join. In this case the initial cluster by is unnecessary. You will have to shuffle at least 2 times: 1) for the group by in my_keys, 2) for the join.

Comment: thanks much... my understanding was that since the repartition was on the same keys policy_num as the join, Spark would reuse this exchange since the key is same.. so how can i reuse a shuffle in such scenarios in general (for performance tuning) ?